# Bootstrap: Input inside a label

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In order to avoid having to have an ID for each input element on my form I would like to place my form input inside the `label` (Bootstrap 3).

My problem is that this is causing extra vertical spacing between rows, the input is not filling the full width of its parent, and the inputs are not aligned.

[image: Illustration]

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="row">
          <span class="col-md-4 control-label">Email:</span>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
          </div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="row">
          <span class="col-md-4 control-label">Password:</span>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
          </div>
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: jsfiddle please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to use the label itself as the `form-group`, remove the `row`, and to add a style to the CSS that sets `display: block` for labels. I have inlined the style in this HTML to show what I mean, obviously you should put it into a CSS.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <label class="form-group" style="display: block">
      <span class="control-label col-md-2">Email:</span>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
      </div>
    </label>
    <label class="form-group" style="display: block">
      <span class="control-label col-md-2">Password:</span>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
      </div>
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: This style is useful:
`label.form-group { display: block; }`

Comment: Div is not a valid element inside of a label element btw

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the extra `row`, since the [`form-group` acts like a `row`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)...

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="email">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="pwd">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/3uRFV0wXG4

Comment: Thanks, but the example you have given doesn't have the labels to the left of the input as per my image, nor does clicking the label activate the input without having to have an ID

Comment: If you dont want them to stack vertical use the `xs` columns. Add the `for=` attribute to the label to activate the inputs on click, Edited my answer

Comment: You have to use the ID, if you want the labels to activate the inputs. This is the intended markup for the form-horizontal: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Comment: This does not answer the question: The OP explicitly wants to avoid the id and for attributes.

Comment: I was answering the problem.. *"this is causing extra vertical spacing between rows, the input is not filling the full width of its parent, and the inputs are not aligned."*, and explaining the intended Bootstrap guidance on form input labels.